# The meaning of "I stripped to him"

Tags: meaning

> “I’m willin’,” I sez; “ but my shtripes are none so ould that I can afford to lose thim. Tell me now, who do I go out wid?” sez I.
>
> He was a quick man an’ a just, an’ saw fwhat I wud be afther. “Wid Mrs. Bragin’s husband,” sez he. He might ha’ known by me askin’ that favour that I had done him no wrong.
>
> We wint to the back av the arsenal an’ **I stripped to him**, an’ for ten minut’s ’twas all I cud do to prevent him killin’ himsilf agin’ my fistes. He was mad as a dumb dog—just frothin’ wid rage; but he had no chanst wid me in reach, or learnin’, or anything else.
>
> “Will ye hear reason?” sez I, whin his first wind was run out.

I'd like to ask the meaning of "I stripped to him"

Source: ["The Solid Muldoon" by Rudyard Kipling](https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/the-solid-muldoon.htm)

Answer (score 5):

From the 'Notes on the text' (which you can find by clicking on 'Background' at top right):

> [Page 44, line 18] **stripped to him** removed upper clothing for a fight.